# How to test apps for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone

I am an iOS app developer. I want to update my apps in time for the release of iPhone 5. However, Apple seems to have not included an iPhone 5 simulator with the GM release of Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6. Not sure how they expect us to update our apps in time for the release of iPhone 5.

Comment: Xcode 4.5 GM seed did include the iPhone 5 simulator with Retina 4" display.

Comment: no idea why this question was closed...probably something that every single iOS developer should know.

Comment: Why is this question closed? I think more votes should be cast for this question so that it can be reopened @Ken White

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you've updated to Xcode 4.5 GM, there's a iPhone 6 simulator. The default screen setting for iPhone 6 simulator is not 4" size, you should set it by

> Hardware (on top menu) -> Device -> iPhone (Retina 4-inch)

Comment: Thank you Kjuly. I overlooked that.