# How can I set the iPhone 5 in simulator in the new XCode 4.5 GM?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, iphone-5, xcode4.5

I'm having some troubles with running/testing my App for the new iPhone.

When running simulator with this newer version of XCode the iPhone 4" is not visible (anymore) under hardware->device.

Did I disabled it or is my XCode broken somehow.

EDIT:

Somehow my Xcode was not running the latest Beta version when running my App via rightmouseclick XCode 4.5 (even though it was listed).

When running XCode via the install file (.dmg) of the developerportal I was able to run the iPhone 4" (iPhone 5) simulator.

Comment: In xcode - Preferences -> Downloads you will find there install button to older simulators (5 only)

Comment: @shannoga I think he means iPhone 5 by - iPhone 4" - (4 inch). Which is included in the XCode 4.5 I think...

Comment: So you say there is no "iPhone (Retina 4-inch)" in the Hardware>Device menu ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434011/how-to-test-apps-for-iphone-5/12434053#12434053

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Download and install Xcode 4.5 (or newer), open your project in it, run in iPhone **6.0** Simulator and then:

[image]

Comment: it cant even fit on my screen properly :D

Comment: press window->scale->50% to fit in your screen