# Xcode iPhone 4, 4s and 5 simulator resolution

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, resolution, xcode4.5

When I run my iPhone app in Xcode simulator, it automatically runs an iPhone 4 or 4s simulator. But I want to test it in iPhone 5 simulator, how can I change the simulator to be a 640x1136px resolution.

Where in Xcode can I find "Change Device Hardwere"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the iPhone 5 in simulator in the new XCode 4.5 GM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462253/how-can-i-set-the-iphone-5-in-simulator-in-the-new-xcode-4-5-gm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this image for change the simulator size

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. I should have figured it by myself.. it's just that I very new to Mac... But you helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Change Device
Hardware>Device>iPhone Retina (4 inch)

Comment: In the menu bar while using the iOS Simulator.

Answer (score -2):

In addition if you want to change the scale size in your screen you can select Window->Scale and change the scale of your visualization. You can chose 50% - 75% - 100% .