# iOS simulator for iPhone 5- 1136 x 640 resolution

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test apps for iPhone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434011/how-to-test-apps-for-iphone-5)

In xcode 4.2 and above we can find the both device for retina display and non retina display.
that means '960-by-640-pixel resolution at 326 ppi' and '480-by-320-pixel resolution at 163 ppi' as iOS Simulator.
(in iOS Simulator menu bar, `Hardware > Device > iPad/iPhone/iPhone(Retina)`).

How can i choose device from Simulator for new iPhone 5 (1136-by-640-pixel resolution at 326 ppi) ..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both Richard and NSPostWhenIdle are correct.  You need to updated to Xcode 4.5 GM, then you'll see an option for "iPhone (Retina 4-inch)", which is the iPhone 5 display.