# iOS Simulator "Inner" Resolution

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I saw the resolution questions:

- [iOS simulator for iPhone 5- 1136 x 640 resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488532/ios-simulator-for-iphone-5-1136-x-640-resolution)

I have done

```
react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPad Pro (9.7 inch)'
```

I even went to "Hardware" menu and selected the device again.

My app launches in dimensions of tablet, however the contents within are not rightly sized, it is *hugely* zoomed. I fixed this accidentally before but I cannot figure it out now. Here is a screenshot of my situation:

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are running a zoomed in iPhone app (which is possible to do on iPad, so the simulator just does its job). You need to set the app from `iPhone` to `Universal` in Xcode. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this, but that's what you should google (imo).

Comment: Thank you @ViktorSeč for that! I will start searching wiith those terms, thanks very much for it! :)

Comment: @ViktorSeč that did the trick! May you please copy paste that comment to answer and I'll put in screenshots of what I did and accept your answer so you get the points! Thank you sooooo much sir!

Comment: cheers, glad that it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are running a zoomed in iPhone app (which is possible to do on iPad, so the simulator does what it's supposed to do). You need to set the app from `iPhone` to `Universal` in Xcode to tell it that your app is targeted for iPad as well.

Comment: Thanks Viktor! From my work computer I will take screenshots and edit it in, you really saved my day thanks!!